# how to know when the tonegenerator has stopped playing

Tags: android, thread-sleep, tone-generator

I kneed to know when my tone generator has stopped playing.

I want to play the dtmf tone for 50 ms and then wait 50 to play the next tone.
i wanted to use this code.

```
private void playtones() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0 ; i<=19 ; i++){
                dtmftone.startTone(savetone.get(i) , 50);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
            }

        }
      ).start();

}
```

The sleep starts before the tone has stopped playing.
How can i check that the tone has stopped playing?
Or is there at better way to do this?

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the method [wait(long millis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) of ToneGenerator instead of Thread.sleep().
Be careful, the method does not wait the sound to have stopped, thus you have to take the duration of the beep into account:

```
int BEEP_DURATION = 50;
int WAITING_DURATION = 50;

...

for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
    dtmftone.startTone(savetone.get(i), BEEP_DURATION);
    synchronized(dtmftone) {
        dtmftone.wait(BEEP_DURATION + WAITING_DURATION);
    }
...
```

And I am not sure whether you want to wait 50ms between two beeps. If you don't, just delete the "+ WAITING_DURATION"